# How can i fire an event upon clicking the image items inside a data list?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am a beginner in Asp.Net. I have a datalist populated with images. What i want is to know what image was clicked so that I can redirect the user to a different page as per the image clicked inside the datalist.

Here is my source:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MediaCenter.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>

<%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.2, Version=11.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        Categories<br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:DataList ID="dtlCat" runat="server" DataKeyField="FolderId" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="96px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="257px" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="False" 
            Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" 
            Font-Underline="False" Caption="Album Gallery" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" OnItemCommand="CatSelect" >
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
            <ItemTemplate>



                <asp:Label ID="FolderNameLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("FolderName") %>'  />
                <br />
                <a href=""><img src="<%# ResolveUrl(String.Format("~/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png", Container.DataItem)) %>" onclick="cat_select" /></a>

                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server"  CommandName="show"  ></asp:LinkButton>

                <asp:Label ID="UrlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
                <br />

                <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />
<br />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AbcWebConnStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Folder]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
&nbsp;</div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given comments inside the code to explain how it works.

**Your HTML Designer :**

```
<asp:datalist id="DataList1" runat="server" onitemcommand="dtlCat_ItemCommand" DataKeyField="FolderId" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="96px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="257px" BorderStyle="Solid" 
            GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="False" 
            Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" 
            Font-Underline="False" Caption="Album Gallery" 
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <ItemTemplate>

         <asp:Label ID="FolderNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FolderName") %>'  />
         <br />

         <%--Here the "ImageID" is the Id coming from your Database--%>
         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgBtnViewInq" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Viewmail.png" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>' ToolTip="View" />

         <%--You can do the same from your link button here too the "ImageID" is the Id coming from your Database--%>    
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server"  CommandName="show" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>' ></asp:LinkButton>

         <asp:Label ID="UrlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
         <br />

         <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
         <br />
         <br />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:datalist>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AbcWebConnStr %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Folder]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**C# Code Behind :**

```
protected void dtlCat_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.CommandName == "View")
     {
         // Here "i" will get the imageid(CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>') that was given inside the image button tag
         int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
         Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx?clickedimgID=" + i);

     }

    if (e.CommandName == "show")
    {
        // Here "i" will get the imageid (CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ImageID") %>') that was given inside the Link button tag

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx?clickedimgID=" + i);

    }

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Right. And how would i know that which image item was clicked?

Comment: CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' pass your Image Id to this

Comment: Ok. But how can i get the ID in my ImageButton_Command event. Its id which is "ImgBtnViewInq" in your example is not visible in the code window. Do i have to declare an ImageButton in my code window and assign it an id. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: In the above case i mentioned the ID comes from the Database where you have stored your Image path. and you assign ID to the button once you bind your datasource with your Datalist. If you are not storing your images into database but wants to display images directly from folder please follow this link : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/cd3aa3/retrieve-all-images-from-a-folder-and-display-them-using-a-datalist-control/

Comment: I've made some changes as per your requirements so Please Check My updated answer, this will help you understand how it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="MediaCenter.aspx.vb" 
   Inherits="Default2" %>

 <%@ Register assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v11.2, Version=11.2.11.0,    
  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a" 
  namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors" tagprefix="dx" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org
  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>

        Categories<br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DataList ID="dtlCat" runat="server" DataKeyField="FolderId" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="96px" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
        RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="257px" BorderStyle="Solid" 
        GridLines="Horizontal" BackColor="White" Font-Bold="False" 
        Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" 
        Font-Underline="False" Caption="Album Gallery" 
        ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
        <ItemTemplate>



            <asp:Label ID="FolderNameLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("FolderName") %>'  />
            <br />
            <a href="yourpage.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("ImageID")%>"><img src="<%# ResolveUrl(String.Format("~/img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png", Container.DataItem)) %>"/> </a>

            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server"  CommandName="show"  ></asp:LinkButton>

            <asp:Label ID="UrlLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Url") %>' />
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" 
                Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
            <br />
          <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:DataList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AbcWebConnStr %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Folder]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
   &nbsp;</div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Hope this may helps you. Let me Know if it helps you.